# Probability in confidence level interval

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Is it possible to determine probability that estimated expected value is inside confidence level interval. When we know confidence level interval.

---

Example using normal distribution. Our random variable $X$ follows normal distribution.
$$ X \sim N(\mu,\sigma) $$
Our $\mu$ and $\sigma$ would be unknown at this example but we do know that we have been able to estimate $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\sigma}$ with confidence level of $95\%$. This would be based on dataset containing $17$ entries.
$$ CI=95\%$$ 
$$ CI_{range}=[5.3,8.0]$$
$$ n=17$$

Problem is that can we determine probability of $\mu$ being in between $[5.3,8.0]$ ?

$$ P(5.3 \le \mu \le 8.0) $$

if we only know estimate for $\mu$ which is $\hat{\mu}$. Could we determine probability of $\mu$ being in between this range ? meaning we dont know value for actual $\mu$ but we want to know probability that the actual $\mu$ is in between this range.

Also our lecturer mentioned that confidence level interval is not same as probability. If someone could explain that why this isn't same as probability ?

One possibility would be that if we could determine the probability this way it would be.

$$P(5.3 \le \mu \le 8.0)=0.95$$  since

$$ \int_{5.3}^{8.0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx \approx 0.95 $$

---

To sum up what would be two mayby possible solutions to this

$(a)$ Probability is 95%

$(b)$ we cannot determine probability.

---

If someone could explain which would be correct solution and why ? any comment or solution towards improving my understanding of this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Tuki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes confidence interval and probability is different. You have correctly calculated the probability it is the area of shaded region from $5.3-8.0$ confidence interval is $\frac {ts}{\sqrt{n}} $ which tells about the range around which population mean lies around the sample mean. Here t=student's constant s=standard deviation of mean,n=number of entries .

Comment: ts would be approximately the actual standard deviation ?
$$ts \approx \sigma $$
Since i know formula which applies to normal distribution and is defined as:

$$ m(x)\pm Z\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} $$

with this we would be able to calculate confidence interval if $\sigma$ is known. m(x) would be good estimate for $\mu$.

$$ m(x)= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}xi $$

You could write confidence interval if $\sigma$ is unknown as:

$$ m(x)\pm t\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}} $$

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: does this apply $$ m(x) \pm t\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}} $$ meaning is this valid expression ?

Comment: Yes its a valid equation as we cannot practically do i finite measurements.